# Checking if input value isn't empty working as wanted

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a few input fields that must be filled before some button becomes active. My code does this, but only works after filling all inputs fields I changed selection from last filled input field to any other. How to make it more dynamic and allow button to become active without changing selection?

```
$(function() {
      $('body').on('change','#form2',function(){
          if($("#name").val() != "" && $("#number").val() != "" && $("#shortname").val() != "")
          {
              $('#CreateConnections').removeAttr("disabled");
          }
          else
          {
              $('#CreateConnections').attr("disabled", true);
          }
      });
  })
```

Comment: Try using `prop` instead of `attr` to start

Comment: Try listening for a `keyUp` instead of a `change` event.

Answer (score 4):

You can try binding both `keyup` and `change` to all input elements. Also:

- instead of using `!=` to evaluate the value, we can simply check the value itself: when not empty it will return true, without the need to make comparisons.
- you should use `.prop()` when working with boolean attributes, like `disabled`, `checked`, `readonly`, `selected` and the likes, instead of `.attr()`. p/s: You should also **avoid** using `.removeProp()` or `.removeAttr()` whenever possible, as once removed they cannot be added back.

Here is the updated jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('change keyup','#form2 :input', function() {
        if($("#name").val() && $("#number").val() && $("#shortname").val()) {
            $('#CreateConnections').prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $('#CreateConnections').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7rK2p/

Comment: Thank you, Terry. Working really smooth and cool! I also got an idea to check minimal length on '#name'. Tried to add var name = $("#name").text().length; and changed if condition to name > 3, but this doesn't work. Can you suggest solution?

Comment: @user2816626 Use `$('#name').val().length > 3`